# Need some modification in my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns total number of users registered on a particular days in 7 days interval time. I also want to get the zero count data so i can plot it on my graph. **How to fetch zero count values?**

The query :

```
select date(update_timestamp) as date, count(*) users
from registered
where date(update_timestamp) between date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 day) and sysdate()
group by date(update_timestamp)
```

I had few problems with my query earlier which was solved on this post http://bit.ly/12irdyf .The problem is solved, however i need modification in my query, now i need to show null values as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best way to keep a calender_table  which has got entries for each date for the year.

```
select    date(update_timestamp) as date, count(*) users
from      calender_table c
left join registered r
on        date(update_timestamp)=c.date
where     c.date between date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 day) and sysdate()
group by  c.date
```

Comment: im binding my chart with a datasource with this query u mentioned. it says db does not have calender_table table :-\

Comment: @Vinayak: create the calender_table in your database.. see this link  http://creative-territory.net/post/view/id/31/

Comment: yup i can do this, however im not allowed to add new table or modify the db... :( u have any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by zero count values? Maybe you need:

```
select date(update_timestamp) as date, count(*) users, '0' AS zero
```

Maybe you wanted to fetch what date it was when you had no users?

Simply locate the date before the first user registered and assign a zero to it like above.

Comment: for example i have 2 users registered  on date 12/11/2012 and 3 users on 12/10/2012. Now my query will display these two count values only (in the interval of 7 days). I want to display rest of the date values with zero as the count